# wxpython GUI .py file compiling with pyinstaller result executable won't run under windows 7

Tags: wxpython, pyinstaller

After several times to do this, i can't do to work, i tried compiling my main .py file with py2exe, cx_freeze and pyinstaller resulting in the same error, see image below.

[Lock hunter and task manager 3 process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0996.jpg)

As you can see, the compiled .exe won't run or show anything and only display in task manager the same 3 process with same amount of Kb and don let me kill process. What happened here?

Also tried compiling the most simple GUI wxpython app and the same result error, my computer is failing?

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

to aside i've try to compiling a simple tkinter app GUI with pyinstaller and run perfectly normal with no error or hangings.

commands i used:

```
pyinstaller --debug --onefile --windowed --noupx setupfreeze.py  
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed setupfreeze.py  
pyinstaller --windowed --noupx setupfreeze.py  
pyinstaller --onefile setupfreeze.py
```

programs:

```
python 2.7.9
pyinstaller 2.1
cx_freeze 4.3.4
wxpython 3.0
Ninja IDE (.py files run Ok)
python module run .py without error and displayed fine
```

Thanks people...

EDIT: py2exe setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 2, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "setupfreeze.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Comment: Seeing your setup file for py2exe may help us troubleshoot some, but it would seem you're dealing with some logic / code problem (or a missing module / import) than anything else.  Without more information there's nothing to help you with here ... ...

Comment: @g.d.d.c See my edit, i put the setup.py for py2exe, i use that simple GUI wxpython app compiled with setup.py not error during process but when i launch the result exe, show the same thing of my image above.

Comment: I tested your code on my computer, compiled an exe and it ran fine.. Seems to be computer specific. I'm using windows 10, python 2.7.10, wx 3.0

Comment: For some reason my AV blocking these compiled .exe when i deactivated run perfectly, so what @user2682863 said _Seems to be computer specific_ was right thanks for help me :)